# Drupal - custom module - Generate dynamic URL alias

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a custom drupal module. I have a demo pages for different APIs I have. (Like, host.com/demo/abc or host.com/demo/bcd or host.com/demo/def ...)

hook_menu()

```
$items['demo/%'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'xxx',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => 'xxx',
        ....
    );
```

I want to change the URL to host.com/abc/demo for all the demo pages. Since I **cannot** a wild card at the beginning of the hook (Like %/demo) I am considering URL alias. But how can I generate url alias dynamically for all the demo pages?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution :
http://www.zyxware.com/articles/3636/drupal-how-to-create-url-alias-for-custom-menu-implementation-of-hook-pathauto

Otherwise :

Before you need to know that all dynamical solution available is not totally safe , take care before using it.

With url_alias you can try this, but you have to restrict by defined path to avoid flood insertion :

```
function mymodule_menu(){
  $items= array();
  $items['demo/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'xxx',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'xxx',
    );
  return $items;
}
function mymodule_init(){
  global $language;
  $path_allowed = array(
    'abc',
    'dbe'
  ); // restrict to avoid flood
  if(arg(1) == 'demo' && in_array(arg(0), $path_allowed)) { // detect demo mode
    $path = arg(1).'/'.arg(0);
    $alias = arg(0).'/'.arg(1);
    $a = db_query('SELECT alias FROM url_alias WHERE source = :source AND alias = :alias', array(':source' => $path, ':alias' => $alias))->fetchField();
    if($a == null) ) {
      db_insert('url_alias')->fields(array(
        'source' => $path,
        'alias' => $alias,
        'language' => $language->language
      ))->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure but you can try this too , you can handle it from hook_init but it can cause some issue form all module loading init

```
function mymodule_init(){
  if(arg(1) == 'demo') { // detect demo mode
    $mycallbacks = array( // define your callback related 
      'abc' => 'mymodule_callback1',
      'dbe' => 'mymodule_callback2',
    );
    if(isset($mycallbacks[arg(0)]) && function_exists($mycallbacks[arg(0)])) { // if  callback is available
      call_user_func($mycallbacks[arg(0)]); // call it
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_callback1(){ //do what you want }
function mymodule_callback2(){ //do what you want }
```

So , mysite.com/abc/demo will execute `mymodule_callback1()` and mysite.com/dbe/demo will execute `mymodule_callback2()`

Etc..

Clear all caches and see :)